# Django question on forms

Tags: python, django, forms, models

Hello I have a django app that has a form that you can add sales and purchase. There is a change I want to make with it. If a user chooses a purchase instead of a sale, I do not want them to have a country type (location). In fact I do not want them to have any value for a purchase.

So to summerise, All sales should have an option to select a country type, while all puchases should not be given this option. How can I do this?

[image]

**models.py**

```
from  management_sys.vat import models   
TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES = ((1, 'sale'), (2, 'purchase'),)  
COUNTRY_TYPE_CHOICES = ((1, 'UK'), (2, 'EU'),)

class Transaction(models.Model):     
    transaction_type = models.Integerfield(verbose_name = "Type", choices = TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES)     
    country_type = models.Integerfield(verbose_name = "Location", choices = COUNTRY_TYPE_CHOICES)     
    date = models.Datefield()     
    vat_period = models.Datefield()     
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)     
    vat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)     
    description models.TextField(MAX_LENGTH = 400)     
    def __unicode__(self):         
        return unicode(self.amount)
```

**forms.py**

```
from management_sys.vat.models import *
from django import forms

class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
```

Comment: The easiest solution would seem to be a two-stage process. Either two forms, first "Type" and second the specific fields; or modify the form dynamically using (e.g.) Ajax.

Comment: Since "sale" and "purchase" are so completely different, it baffles me how one form can cover both cases.  Why are you trying to do this with one confusing form?

Comment: `@S.Lott: ` I've created two table instead like you said. Create I for sales and another one for purchases. And I will leave this way instead of doing something more complecated

Answer (score 0):

This question is not really django related. You should do that via javascript: hide or show some field base on <select> value.

The only thing is form validation. You should perform it like that in your case:

```py
   from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

   class Transaction(models.Model):
       # your fields

       def clean(self):
           if self.transaction_type == 2 and self.country_type:
               raise ValidationError(u'You must not fill location with "purchase" option.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript for this. If you're using {{ form.as_table }} then by using jQuery it'll look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        showOrHideLocation();
        $('#id_transaction_type').change(showOrHideLocation);
    });
    function showOrHideLocation() {
        if ($('#id_transaction_type option:selected[value=1]').length) {
            $('#id_country_type').parents('tr:first').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#id_country_type').parents('tr:first').hide();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Then just validate your result in your forms.